# Is Live SDK deprecated?

Tags: onedrive, live-sdk

As I have understand - Live SDK has supporting 2 main features:
OneDrive and Microsoft account

Now with release OneDrive SDK all OneDrive features are coud be found in it.
But if you want to access Microsoft Account you still can use only Live SDK.

Seems that now we have 2 branches - Live SDK and OneDrive SDK.
One for account and another for files.
I am asking because sometimes it's not clearly written and looks like live SDk is depricated.

Comment: I have a similar question.  I commented below.  Do we still use the live API for OAuth 2.0 but use the new OneDrive API?  That's the way it appears to work in the samples.  When using the new Outlook APIs we use a different OAuth2.0 flow.   login.microsoftonline.com vs login.live.com.  It is NOT clear if login.live.com is deprecated for OAuth 2.0 flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are deprecated according to this:

> The Live Connect APIs are deprecated. We recommend that you use the
>   Outlook REST APIs to build your solutions. This will extend your reach
>   to Outlook.com users and Office 365 enterprise customers. Although the
>   Live Connect APIs will be supported in Outlook.com for the short term,
>   existing Live Connect API solutions might stop working without
>   advanced notice. If your app is using IMAP with OAuth 2.0, it will
>   continue to work, but our REST APIs are the primary APIs for building
>   apps that connect to Outlook.com and Office 365. Read the article on
>   how you can take advantage of the Outlook REST APIs.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx

Comment: Thank you, Johnno. It's a little bit more clear now, but still not absolutely, while there is also Office 365 API with which it's possible also to get account information

Comment: I was just going to ask a similar question.  It's clear the OneDrive Live SDK APIs are deprecated, but in for the OAuth 2.0 flow it appears, even from MS's examples, that we use the Live OAuth 2.0 flow instead of the new Microsoft Online OAuth 2.0 flow (that is used if you want to use the Outlook APIs).  Very confusing.  If we could get some info from Microsoft it would sure help.